# ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature error

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode11, code-signing-certificate

This is the error message I get while uploading my app binary to iTunesConnect:

`ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature - The bundle 'com.myCompany.myApp' at bundle path 'Payload/myApp.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.`

I compared the settings with another app of mine I successfully upload and hardly see any difference in the certificates or signing settings.
Only one thing is different, though: myApp has an extension (Ads blocker) while the other one has none (but I don't think it makes any difference).

I searched through the internet for any fixes or things to be done, but I am left in the same situation, the app is turned as invalid binary for this very issue.

Happy to receive help on that.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be something Apple have broken their end as lots of developers are experiencing the same issue:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/133781

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solution for this.

Update:

Solution: 1

I have applied a quick fix found in the forum and that worked for me..

from the forum I used `--deep` in `Other Code Sign in Flag` for the project target and that worked for me. Hope this will help who are very much in need to get their project to the testflight.

Update2: 
Solution 2:

What i have found that the problem is occurring due to previous bundle id created for app but not uploading app build to the appstore connect before updating to new xcode.

So, what i did is, I changed the bundle id. delete provision folder from mobile device folder at library. clear the build folder and then re archive and it's working now perfectly without any problem.

Hope this helps you.
Any other solution would be much more appreciated.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca please checked that if have done like this link bellow or not? and also clear the provision folder
https://images.guru/i/LbvWW

If still does not work follow the solution 2. I have tried both they both worked for me.. though...

Comment: Btw, for solution 2, I cannot change the bundle I’d as the app has been previously submitted. Currently I try a third thing: I created a brand new app in ITC with a new bundle ID to see whether this build actually work. Waiting for the build upload process to complete.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca are you still having the issue?.. if you are.. then try to cmd + option + shift + k to clean everything. then close xcode and  then go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData  from finder and  delete the Derived data, delete provision folder from mobile device folde  then try to open your project and archive it .. hope this will solve this problem..